# Read cookie inside HostedService

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

Working under ASP.net core 2.2 with Razzor page :
I'm using a background services using SingalR and I want to use a token (store in cookie) in this background service.
I want to get my HttpContext in the background service class How can I get it ?

My tries : Getting httpcontext from the startup.cs (I guest it is impossible)

Startup.cs :

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSignalR();

    // context isnt defined
    var token = context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "API")?.Value;
    services.AddHostedService<MyBackgroundClass>(token);
}
```

Second try : Getting the httpcontext from with dependency injection ?

MyBackgroundClass.cs :

```cs
[Authorize]
public class MyBackgroundClass : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IHubContext<BigScreenHub> _hub;
    private readonly List<WorkerInfo> WorkerInfos;
    public MyBackgroundClass(IHubContext<BigScreenHub> hub, IOptions<AppSettings> settings, ...)
    {
        _hub = hub;
        WorkerInfos = new WorkerInfoProvider(settings.Value.SomeStaticParam,"Need token here", settings.Value.ServicesUrl).WorkerInfos;
    }
}
```

Comment: From the looks of it you're trying to have your background glass execute the updates for your web sockets. I've done something similar in the past.  Just store all of the information that you need in custom object and pass it to the background worker when you queue the task.

Comment: In a static class you mean ? Static is really trustable ? Sometime I got some random release

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about. If its a a token for configuration it should be resolved during the backgroundservice start up, but if thats the case You shouldn't need the HTTPContext at all for that.  If the token is related to the user, then the hosted service should be more generic and just execute a task and you pass all the data required to execute that task when an event occurs

Comment: I'm looking at your code.  I don't understand why you need the API token aren't you the API? can you explain what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Background service is not connected to HttContext in any way.

The HttpContext exists only in the Controller when consuming a web request and it can be provided by dependency injection.

Comment: What can I do ?

Comment: In case you don't need a httpcontex in the constructor. You can create controllers an process theirs web calls.

Comment: In the idea, I can even strat the background service in the login contructor. Somethink like ``services.AddHostedService<MyBackgroundClass>(myToken);`` in the Login Contructor, but how can I do this in a Controller ?

Comment: Hyro, the background service should not be specific to a token, you probably should just be uses the QueueBackground service and pass the token along with the Data you need to send back in a custom object

Comment: Do you have some more infos about the usage of QueueBackground ?

Comment: @Hyro, yeah its in the documentation [here] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#queued-background-tasks).  if you're looking for a hosted service which automatically pushs changes to it's subscribers.   I have it, but I can't post it as an answer until you rephrase the question to request it

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid accessing cookies from HostedService, since cookies only exist when there is request, but, for Hosted Service, it is running all the time, you may access a null object where there is no request.

For accessing cookies, you could try `IHttpContextAccessor` like

```
    [Authorize]
    public class MyBackgroundClass : BackgroundService
    {
    private readonly IHubContext<BigScreenHub> _hub;
    private readonly List<WorkerInfo> WorkerInfos;
    private readonly HttpContext _httpContext;
    public MyBackgroundClass(IHubContext<BigScreenHub> hub, IOptions<AppSettings> settings, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
            _httpContext = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
            _hub = hub;
            WorkerInfos = new WorkerInfoProvider(settings.Value.SomeStaticParam,"Need token here", settings.Value.ServicesUrl).WorkerInfos;
    }
    }
```